# How to get the w_organization_social and r_organization_social permission to post a content into a company page using LinkedIn API?

Tags: python, http, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the [LinkedIn API endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http) provided by LinkedIn:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts
```

In that documentation, it is mentioned that these permissions are mandatory:
[image]

---

Currently, I have a token that has these permissions:

- r_emailaddress
- opened
- profile
- r_liteprofile
- w_member_social
- email

I get these permissions by easily clicking `Request_access` on the developer page.

[image]

---

My question is how do I get the `w_organization_social` and `r_organization_social` permissions?